# Get database ID from a row in ListView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a `ListView` in ASP.NET where one column contains `CheckBox`. In order to get the database updated when the users change click them, I use `OnCheckedChanged`. But how do I know which record in the database each checkbox is related to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the DataKeys property to the string which represents the individual record ID.

Once you are in the Item Data Bound event you can then reference the ID value using;

```
DataKey currentDataKey = myListView.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex];
```

You then simply lookup your database record using the currentDataKey value.

Comment: But how can I use that information when OnCheckedChanged is fired? I have many CheckBoxes.

Comment: When you setup your template why not set the value of the checkbox to be the ID for the row? That way when your checkbox fires you have the ID that you need to look up to identify your record and do whatever is required?

Answer (score 0):

The CheckBox control has a `Parent` property, which should translate to the ListViewItem; if it doesn't, you can try a series of `.Parent.Parent.etc` and one of the parents will be the list box item.

HTH.