# Update the database asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView in ASP.NET where one column consists checkBoxes. I want the user to be able to these CheckBoxes directly in the list (without having to go into edit mode). How I do that, I have received answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983132/get-database-id-from-a-row-in-listview-in-asp-net)

The problem is when the user quickly press several CheckBoxes. It is only the first checkBox that is stored in the database, the other is restored. The user must for every checkBox, wait for the page updated. Is it posible to solve so that the changes are written to the database asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UpdatePanel`  to  write to the database asynchronously and set `Trigger` to  `CheckedChanged`  event

Comment: I added a UpdatePanel in the <ItemTemplate> for the ListView. But if I change many checkBoxes and then do any postpack, then the last changed is not saved. How to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

You should make Ajax request using JavaScript on checkbox state change